# Reading List (Advanced Alpha Design)

Tags: big-list

I am busy working on a getting started guide for advanced quantitative finance (for alpha design) and have been searching for the seminal books/literature for the field.

So far I have the following list but I feel as if I must be missing a few texts:

- [Active Portfolio Management](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Active-Portfolio-Management-quantative-producing/dp/0070248826/ref=sr_1_12?keywords=portfolio+management&qid=1561568578&s=gateway&sr=8-12)
- [Quantitative Equity Portfolio Management](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Quantitative-Equity-Portfolio-Management-Construction-ebook/dp/B000N2HBYI/ref=dp_kinw_strp_1)
- [Expected Returns by Antti Ilmanen](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Expected-Returns-Investors-Harvesting-Rewards/dp/1119990726)
- [Advances in Financial Machine Learning](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Advances-Financial-Machine-Learning-Marcos-ebook/dp/B079KLDW21/ref=dp_kinw_strp_1)
- [Options, Futures, and Other Derivatives](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Options-Futures-Other-Derivatives-Global/dp/1292212896/ref=pd_sim_14_15?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=1292212896&pd_rd_r=4f7241eb-9834-11e9-9b6b-671de1e84b51&pd_rd_w=f3kd7&pd_rd_wg=eLHMO&pf_rd_p=1b8636ae-4f21-4403-a813-e8849dd46de4&pf_rd_r=EGBRV1P34NV3E3XX8BHY&psc=1&refRID=EGBRV1P34NV3E3XX8BHY)
- [Online Portfolio Selection](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Online-Portfolio-Selection-Principles-Algorithms-ebook/dp/B07KTDVNC6/ref=sr_1_1?keywords=online+portfolio+selection&qid=1561569326&s=gateway&sr=8-1)
- [AQR's 20 for Twenty](https://www.aqr.com/Insights/Research/Book/20-for-Twenty)

Are there any other great texts that we should add? I am open to the idea of academic papers as well.

2 Examples of knock out good papers (imo) are:

1. [Empirical Asset Pricing via Machine Learning](http://dachxiu.chicagobooth.edu/download/ML.pdf)
2. [Building Diversified Portfolios that Outperform Out of Sample](https://jpm.iijournals.com/content/42/4/59)

Answer (score 3):

my personal favorite in addition to APM is [Quantitative Equity Investing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470262478). I think of it as alpha 101 as it goes thru modelling time series, covariance matrix, then to factor portfolio optimization, transaction costs etc.

Answer (score 1):

What about [Empirical Asset Pricing](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Empirical-Asset-Pricing-Cross-Section-Probability/dp/1118095049/ref=sr_1_1?crid=RBCFRTH73VBM&keywords=empirical%20asset%20pricing&qid=1563179114&s=books&sprefix=empirical%20ass%2Cstripbooks%2C124&sr=1-1)? A standard book about many known anomalies and ways of detecting/testing them. May help to generate some alpha when strategies around these ideas are exploided.